# Asp.net authentication checks

Tags: asp.net, security

I have an asp.net webforms project. What is the standard way of adding business logic authentication checks throughout an application in all the areas that need protection?

For example, Page X can only be viewed by someone labeled 'Admin'.

A more complex example: only a user who belong to a group of people who manages users A,B, and C can modify user A,B, or C's profile information.

I can go on and on about the hundreds of places and types of authentication checks needed, but basically the only way I know to do this is to have lots of custom code run at the beginning of every button click handler, page_load, GridView rowChange, etc that will first check some business logic and then either allow it or return.

More generally, is it even necessary to have these business logic authentication checks for basically every postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the checks are role based and chunky, e.g. "Admin" role can execute all code on this page, but no one else can-- then use roles cached in your FormsAuthentication cookie and an PrinciplePermission attribute, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731200.aspx  You can also put these attributes on methods.  But, they don't allow for complex authorization checks and aren't easy to change without recompiling code.

If the checks are only partially role based and granular, e.g. Secretaries can click this, Admins can view this, Joe can view this on the weekends, etc. Then you need the authorization checks in your code behind. You have to re-execute your authorization checks unless you can cache the result somewhere secure. You can cache the results in ViewState if ViewState is encrypted.

If you don't check authorization on postback, you are vulnerable to custom crafted posts that invoke events on disabled buttons, invisible buttons, etc. By encrypting viewstate and keeping event validation on, you can mitigate this sort of thing some too.

Factor your code into utility classes and base classes to minimize the duplication.